# Using .map affecting the whole object (making it undefined) rather than updating property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I do:

```
csvParse(txtString, {columns: true})
```

I get an array of objects, within this I want to update a certain property for each object.

But all that's happening is the object is becoming undefined.

This works exactly as I would expect it:

```
let x = [{
  y: 123,
  z: 'abc'
}, {
  y: 456,
  z: 'efg'
}, {
  y: 789,
  z: 'hij'
}];

console.log(x);

x.map(x => {
  x.z.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(x); // no changes saved

x.map(x => {
  x.z = x.z.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(x); //now z is uppercase
```

However when I do the same in my code:

```
resolve(
  csvParse(txtString, {
    columns: true
  })
  .map(x => {
    x.categories = x.categories
      .replace(regexes.doubleQuotesOrSquareBrackets, '')
      .split(',');
  })
);
```

Every element in the results array becomes undefined.

Comment: "I get an array of objects, within this I want to update a certain property for each object."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way ES6 functions work, is that it returns computed value when there is a single statement, if there are multiple statements then you need to explicitly use `return`

In your case, your single statement is an assignment operation.

So it technically returns `undefined`

```
.map(x => {
       x.categories = ...
});
```

is nothing but

```
.map(x => {
       x.categories = ...
       return undefined;
});
```

To fix it you can either do

```
.map(x => {
       x.categories = ...;
       return x.categories;
});
```

**OR**

```
.map(x => {
    ...;
    return x;
});
```

Comment: @CraigHarley If you are expecting it to return `x` then sure.

Comment: brilliant thanks for your help, I'll accept the answer when it lets me.

I find it strange that it doesn't return it automatically, since it's still sort of one statement (as they are chained)

Comment: If you had written the statement as `{
    x.categories
      .replace(regexes.doubleQuotesOrSquareBrackets, '')
      .split(',');
  }` then it would have worked as expected. But it got messed up due to the assignment operation.

Comment: Shouldn't the assignment to that object be mutating on its source?

Comment: Yes It would mutate the source. It is just not seen as the return is not the original object.